# Restore from iTunes does not restore app data?

Tags: iphone, itunes, restore

I just restored my iPhone from iTunes. At backup time a Bitcoin app was installed on iPhone, with an already created wallet with a balance. After restore, Copay in on iPhone, but when starting the wallet balance is not included in the app. Why?

Comment: Was this an encrypted backup?  Also, does the developer of that app indicate this type of data will be included in any backups?

Comment: Unfortunately it was not an encrypted backup.

Comment: I don't know for sure, but for unencrypted backups, some app data is not included.  I recommend contacting the developer of that Bitcoin app and ask about this.

Comment: *always* use an encrypted backup, even if the password is just "1234." It saves all your passwords, at least, WiFi and others. At worst it is a convenience at best...

Comment: Agreed. But if you forget it, you'll have to be on iOS 11 to remove it and do a newer backup.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wallets and apps that store sensitive data usually store passwords/encryption keys in keychain. If the backup was not encrypted, unfortunately, only app developers may be able to help.

Also, some banking apps and wallets don't include this data in the backup and have another way of transferring accounts or passwords.

p.s. @Steve Chambers is right, you should always have an encrypted backup, even with an easy password like '12345', just to back up as mutch data as possible.